# How to find first positive value and third consecutive positive values in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have tried using ROW_NUMBER but haven't quite got it. Any ideas on the best way to achieve this.

I am looking to find:

```
- What month did they first cash flow.

- What month did they average 3 months cash flow.
```

**Sample Data**:
Office ,Balance & Year month

```
  ------------------------------
  |  Office | Balance |  YrMo  |
  |   12    |  111    | 201510 |
  |   12    |  222    | 201511 |
  |   12    | -444    | 201512 |
  |   12    | -777    | 201601 |
  |   12    |  555    | 201602 |
  |   12    |  666    | 201603 |
  |   12    | -888    | 201604 |
  |   12    |  777    | 201605 |
  |   40    | -555    | 201510 |
  |   40    | -200    | 201511 |
  |   40    |  0      | 201512 |
  |   40    |  100    | 201601 |
  |   40    | -555    | 201602 |
  |   40    |  666    | 201603 |
  |   40    |  777    | 201604 |
  |   40    |  888    | 201605 |
  |   40    |  999    | 201606 |
```

The first Positive Balances would be:

```
-office 12 , Balance 111 , YrMo 201510
-office 40 , Balance 100 , YrMo 201601
```

The first month the office averaged 3 positive balance:

```
-office 40 , Balance 999 , YrMo 201606
```

Here is the #test table script:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #test
GO

CREATE TABLE #test (office INT , Balance INT, YrMo INT ) ;

INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (12 ,  111 , 201510) ;
INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (12 ,  222 , 201511) ;
INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (12 , -444 , 201512) ;
INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (12 , -777 , 201601) ;
INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (12 ,  555 , 201602) ;
INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (12 ,  666 , 201603) ;
INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (12 , -888 , 201604) ;
INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (12 ,  777 , 201605) ;
INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (40 , -555 , 201510) ;
INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (40 , -200 , 201511) ;
INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (40 ,  0   , 201512) ;
INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (40 , 100  , 201601) ;
INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (40 , -555 , 201602) ;
INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (40 , 666  , 201603) ;
INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (40,  777  , 201604) ;
INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (40 , 888  , 201605) ;
INSERT  INTO #test VALUES  (40 , 999  , 201606) ;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `-office 40 , Balance 400 , YrMo 201601` record does not exist in your Sample Data: Office ,Balance & Year month

Comment: Typo, I meant:   
     
        -office 40 , Balance 100 , YrMo 201601

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cteFirst as (
    Select *
          ,FirstPos=Row_Number() over (Partition By Office Order By YrMo,Balance) from #Test  Where Balance>0 
),
  cteCons as (
    Select * 
          ,TestCons=Lag(IIf(IIf(sign(balance)=1,1,0)=1,1,0),1,0) over (Partition By Office Order By YrMo)
                   +Lag(IIf(IIf(sign(balance)=1,1,0)=1,1,0),2,0) over (Partition By Office Order By YrMo)
                   +Lag(IIf(IIf(sign(balance)=1,1,0)=1,1,0),3,0) over (Partition By Office Order By YrMo)
    from #Test 
)
Select *,Status='First Positive' from cteFirst where FirstPos=1
Union All
Select *,Status='3 Cons' from cteCons where TestCons=3
```

Return

```
office  Balance YrMo    FirstPos    Status
12      111     201510  1           First Positive
40      100     201601  1           First Positive
40      999     201606  3           3 Consequtive
```

Comment: I've never used the IIf expression before but I can get an idea of what its doing. The other approach I was thinkin of is adding a [Month #] column to  capture months from Date(190001) then inner join the table on its self Yrmo + 1 , then inner join twice more to filter ...

Comment: IIF is the inline if.  Same as the case just shorter

Comment: You can run each cre individually to better understand what is going on

Comment: I had one quick question. What if there was a gap in dates , what would be another approach using but using the same general idea of the two main cte (first & cons)?

Comment: If a gap in dates... the gaps would be ignored  the data is ordered within the OVER clause

Comment: Few items: 1) I'm sure can be done with temp tables and such.  2) Trapping date gaos could be done by casting YrMo and Int (trapping for year change.  3) Apparently I can't spell consecutive

Answer (score 1):

I added another example.  This one traps gaps in Dates.

> If you want to see all the flags and how the data progresses, remove
>   the -- before **Select * from cteFinal Order by Office,YrMo**

I added another office which has 3 consecutive positive balances, but the months are NOT (no June).  Notice Office 99 fails to meet the consecutive months criteria

```
office  Balance YrMo
99      199     201605
99      299     201607
99      399     201608
```

The updated query is as follows

```
;with cteBase as (
    Select *
          ,RowNr  = Row_Number() over (Partition By Office Order By Office,YrMo,Balance) 
          ,MthSeq = case when cast(YrMo as int)-Lag(YrMo,1,YrMo-1) over (Partition By Office Order By YrMo) in (1,89) then 1 else 0 end
          ,IsPos  = IIf(Balance>0,1,null)
     from #Test
)
,cteFinal as (
    Select *
          ,PosRowNr = min(RowNr*IsPos) over (Partition By Office Order By RowNr) 
          ,TestCons = MthSeq * (
                      Lag(IIf(IIf(sign(balance)=1,1,0)=1,1,0),1,0) over (Partition By Office Order By YrMo)
                     +Lag(IIf(IIf(sign(balance)=1,1,0)=1,1,0),2,0) over (Partition By Office Order By YrMo)
                     +Lag(IIf(IIf(sign(balance)=1,1,0)=1,1,0),3,0) over (Partition By Office Order By YrMo)
                     )
    From  cteBase
)
--Select * from cteFinal Order by Office,YrMo
Select Office
      ,Balance
      ,YrMo
      ,Status = IIf(RowNr=PosRowNr,'First Positive','')+IIf(TestCons=3,'Consecutive Months','')
 From cteFinal 
 Where TestCons=3 or RowNr=PosRowNr
 Order by Status Desc,Office,YrMo
```

The Results are

```
Office  Balance YrMo    Status
12      111     201510  First Positive
40      100     201601  First Positive
99      199     201605  First Positive
40      999     201606  Consecutive Months
```

Comment: I cant thank you enough. Your type of responses not only teach and show but genuinely make us more passionate about finding the best solutions. Once I get enough points I will upvote you. Again Thank you

Comment: Very kind words.  Thank you.  Passion is the absolute right word.  Been doing this for years and still dig the puzzles.  Cheers